# How to load a file into a string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending some email in an asp.net mvc application, and I want to place some html templates in a folder.

If I place a template file in a folder under Models e.g. `Models\EmailTemplates\MyTemplate.html` how do I load this file into a string (to be later used as the email body). I want to use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`. How do I reference the file location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string path = "~/Models/EmailTemplates/MyTemplate.html";
string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
```

Use Server.MapPath

Comment: `Server.MapPath` works by itself. However, VS 2015 could not resolve HttpContext.Current (I am calling from within a Controller action)

Comment: Added namespace before HttpContext to resolve it. Check now

Comment: Good. Happy to help